# Merge MySQL and SQL Server Data Sources for Reporting

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reporting

We have data stored for our customers in MySQL (Web App) and other data stored in SQL Server (billing data) and now we have a need to report on this data inside our customer-facing application.

Does anyone have experience merging these two data sources? Is there an effective way to do this?

Are there existing solutions, preferably OSS, that can aggregate the data sources and allow them to be queried as though they were one (this would be ideal)?

Otherwise, without asking for the "best" solution, what is optimal in this situation? Should we merge the separate sources into one database nightly? This is the only thing I can think of off the bat, and am wondering (hoping) whether other, more elegant or robust solutions exist.

Ideally we'd be able to query the data in real-time, rather than working off of a daily upload or whatever.

Comment: what are you using for the customer-facing application? you can have two connections one to MySQL and one to SQL server and query both

Comment: My approach would be to use ODBC to connect to both databases and retreive the data that you need.

Comment: Querying both databases isn't the issue, I could easily juggle a couple database connections. The thing is, all of this data is relational, and so having a singular interface to query on would provide an added level of robustness. What I'd hoped to accomplish was basically writing a SQL statement that was ran on a 'superficial' database that was created from the aggregate of the other two. Does this make sense? Am I asking for miracles here?

Comment: you can make views out of aggregate functions and sync the aggregates from both databases to a new mysql instance over night. That's another approach

Comment: @SamD I've considered that, and this is an internally developed site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to write queries across the two db then you could link the MySQL to the SQL Server 
- something like this

http://coresystems.ch/en/about-us/newsroom/category/blog/how-add-linked-server-connection-mysql-mssql/

Comment: Do you know of anything that works  in the other direction, allowing me to link the MSSQL DB to the MySQL DB? I'd like to prevent adding any Windows servers to our stack. Otherwise this looks to be exactly what we need.

Comment: unfortunately I've only done the linking inside of SQL Server (and once linked you can query the dbs as one which is really handy). I've seen this link which indicates something has similar is now possible from inside MySQL (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_DataController) but I can't vouch for it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a third party reporting engine, then, you can give [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/) a spin, it lets you [combine different databases in one single query](http://www.dbxtra.com/help-file/query.htm#Heterogeneous__Query) to produce a report, it even lets you do so graphically, so you don't have to write the query yourself.